# Why gcc is complaing about gets()

Tags: c, function, gcc, declaration

This is my code(simplified):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 240

int main(void)
{
    char word[SIZE];
    gets(word);

    return 0;
}
```

Why GCC is giving me

`№3.c: In function ‘main’:
№3.c:13:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

this warning?

GCC vesion is 5.2.1

P.S.The program is working.

P.P.S. I will never use gets(), I will never use gets(), I will never use gets(), I will never use gets()

Comment: Which version of GCC? Version 5 and later uses C11 as default dialect (with GCC extensions) which means that `gets` doesn't actually exist anymore (it was removed in the C11 standard).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: ~~GCC 5 still doesn't produce a warning when compiling this program, though (and it does compile)~~. Scratch that, my system's borked. :(

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Question updated

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis  Question updated

Comment: It could be a C standard library issue (not a compiler one). But `gets` is obsolete and dangerous, so don't use it.

Comment: there are two main reasons for not using `gets()`  (and why it produces a warning message)  (suggest using `fgets()` instead)  1) it does not limit the number of characters that the user can input, which means the input buffer, in your code, `word[size]` can be easily overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour.  2) due to #1, it has been removed from the latest C standard (c11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `gets` is not supported by the C Standard any more because it is an unsafe function. So it seems the function declaration was excluded from the header `<stdio.h>` and now the compiler does not know what is the declaration of the `gets`.

From the C Standard (Foreword)

> 6 This third edition cancels and replaces the second edition, ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999, as corrected by ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 1:2001, ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999/Cor 2:2004, and ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 3:2007. Major changes
>   from the previous edition include:

...

```
— removed the gets function (<stdio.h>)
```

Comment: @Zhigalin The compiler can issue a warning but keep the function for the backward compatibility.